# How to access to Netsuite error log

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I received automated email error from Netsuite.

```
Account: 45447
Environment: SandBox
Date & Time: 7/20/2017 3:55 pm
Record Type: Invoice
Internal ID: 6974547
Execution Time: 0.00s
Script Usage: 0
Script: Invoice Pingback
Type: User Event
Function: afterSubmitInvoice
Error: UNEXPECTED_ERROR
Ticket: j5bwm0cu2oj2ilksh
Stack Trace: nlapiRequestURL(invoice_pingback2.js$25817:1129)
afterSubmitInvoice(invoice_pingback2.js$25817:13)
<anonymous>(invoice_pingback2.js$25817:18)
```

My question, is there any details log in Netsuite that I can access and view more about this error.  It's an UNEXPECTED_ERROR but I need to know more details about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a chance that the script was coded with some logging statements. You can check by going to:

Customization > Scripting > Script Execution Logs

And then filter by that script (Invoice Pingback). You might be able to figure out what caused this. From the looks of it the script was trying to make an HTTP call and something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Execution log might not show every details, create a saved search for "Server Script Log" define your criteria accordingly - it will yield more data than execution log.